# Align armature to NON standard axes/planes

Tags: armature

I'm trying to adapt a pre-existing airplane skeletal mesh to *animate* it (the resulting model will be imported in **UE4**). I designed a number of bones to *move* many parts with good result but I got stuck animating ailerons the problem arise from *hinge* orientation:

[image: Aileron and Armature view (X axis)]

As you can notice aileron is not parallel to any of the standard planes. Moreover the face of the plane where the Armature have been *attached* is not orthogonal to the aileron surface.

[image: Aileron view]

How can I force armature to be orthogonal to one of the aileron surfaces and parallel to its hinge line?

[image: Aileron view (Z axis) - the highlighted line in the top is the hinge line]

Of course If I change `Transformation orientation` to `local` the `Pose` mode works fine but:

1. I think it works only inside Blender;
2. it applies globally while I just need to apply this kind of transformation only to this specific Armature.

Comment: select the entire bone in edit mode and rotate it on its Y axis, or in pose mode, change its roll.

Comment: @MartyFouts it sounds like a retry-error procedure... there's a way to *align* the bone ?

Comment: If you know the angle you can apply it numerically.  Otherwise, have a look into using [custom orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html) so you can snap the bone to the plane

Comment: @MartyFouts I don't know the angle...

Comment: try creating a custom orientation and snapping the bone to it, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the armature in the local space of the object works for you in this case, but you may find that you sometime have a surface that does not lie in the object's space to which you must align a bone.  You can do that by using snapping and recalculating roll in conjunction with the cursor:

[image]

1. We start with an armature and a bone in default global axes, and a surface that's flat but not aligned to anything in particular.
2. We select two vertices on the surface (in median pivot) and snap the cursor to selected.  Then we select the head of the bone in edit mode and snap selected to the cursor.
3. We select two more vertices for snapping the tail of the bone.
4. We select a new set of vertices to indicate where the bone's Z axis should point and snap cursor to selected.  Then in edit mode, we select the bone and use the "recalculate roll->cursor" operation (from ctrl n menu for me.)

The bone is now perfectly aligned to the surface.

You can also use techniques involving creating a constraint and then applying the pose as rest pose, which is sometimes more convenient for some exact positioning.

Comment: that was the answer I was waiting for. Thnx,

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be easily solved setting `Local transformation orientation`.
The setting propagate to each bone in the mesh but in this specific case it works and *survive* the export in .fbx format.

[image]